# How to convert datetime.datetime to array?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, scipy, mat-file

I have an array that contains datetime.datetime objects. They are as follows:

```
array([datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 3, 32, 262000),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 5, 7, 290000),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 6, 45, 383000),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 8, 23, 335000)], dtype=object)
```

I am trying to save this data as a .mat file using savemat through this command.

```
save_structure = {'Time':time_array}
savemat(path + '\2011.mat',save_structure)
```

Here `.mat` is the matlab format file.

I have used the following libraries:

```
from spacepy import pycdf
from scipy.io import savemat,loadmat
import datetime
```

It gives me the following error:

`TypeError: Could not convert 2011-01-01 00:03:32.262000 (type <class 'datetime.datetime'>) to array`

One of the ways through which I was getting through was by converting the following data into Unix but now I need these particular data for ease in my further data analysis. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to?

Comment: What *does* a datetime look like as an array‽

Comment: My apologies for the incomplete question. I have explained it further. @deceze

Comment: @ShivankChadda Can you provide more of the code? Which libs you use to create the object and what is the `savemat` command? Is .mat supposed to be a matlab format file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `datetime.datetime` to `numpy.datetime64` first, then scipy seems to know how to handle the conversion:

```
import datetime

import numpy as np
from scipy.io import savemat

time_array = np.array([datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 3, 32, 262000),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 5, 7, 290000),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 6, 45, 383000),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 8, 23, 335000)])

time_array_np = time_array.astype(np.datetime64)
save_structure = {'Time': time_array_np}
savemat('2011.mat', save_structure)
```